# Reverse query for Hierarchical Data

Tags: sql-server

I have seen one article
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
 That use below data from category table

```
  category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
```

In the below query and returns below data.

```
  SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
 FROM category AS t1
 LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
 LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
 LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
 WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS';

 +-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
 | lev1        | lev2                 | lev3         | lev4  |
 +-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
 | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | TUBE         | NULL  |
 | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | LCD          | NULL  |
 | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | PLASMA       | NULL  |
 | ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | MP3 PLAYERS  | FLASH |
 | ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | CD PLAYERS   | NULL  |
 | ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 2 WAY RADIOS | NULL  |
 +-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now my question is if I have a table or query that has below data

```
  +-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
  | lev1        | lev2                 | lev3         | lev4  |
  +-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
  | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | TUBE         | NULL  |
  | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | LCD          | NULL  |
  | ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | PLASMA       | NULL  |
  | ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | MP3 PLAYERS  | FLASH |
  | ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | CD PLAYERS   | NULL  |
  | ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 2 WAY RADIOS | NULL  |
  +-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
```

How I can make a Reverse query that returns below data:

```
   category_id | name                 | parent |
   +-------------+----------------------+--------+
 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
 |           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
 |           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
 |           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
 |           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
 |           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
 |           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
 |           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
 |           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
 |          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
```

If I could have also value of level field (0 or 1 or...) in this reverse query was very good.

```
   category_id | name                 | parent |position

   +-------------+----------------------+--------+-------
 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |0
 |           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |0
 |           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |3
 |           4 | LCD                  |      2 |1
 |           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do the IDs come from? Suppose, you have another table with IDs per item, then the code could look similar to this:

```
select i.ID, l.lev1 as Name, NULL as Parent
from IDTable i 
     join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev1
union
select i.ID, l.lev2 as Name, (select j.ID from IDTable j where j.Name = l.lev1)
from IDTable i 
     join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev2
union
select i.ID, l.lev3 as Name, (select j.ID from IDTable j where j.Name = l.lev2)
from IDTable i 
     join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev3
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot after 10 days searching in a lot of forums, now  just I have 2 question:
1- About (Suppose, you have another table with IDs per item) you mean I have to define new table with autonumber ID,item  and then  insert all the items from all the levels with distinct key word to that.

2- How I can have also position field in my query. For example parent of TUBE, LCD, PLASMA are TELEVISIONS now I need position field value that gives value of each position (0, 1, 2, 3…) according to alphabetic order.