# position value of each field in query

Tags: sql-server

Before I have a question about (Reverse query for Hierarchical Data)
[Reverse query for Hierarchical Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335772/reverse-query-for-hierarchical-data)

I got 90% of my answer.

```
select i.ID, l.lev1 as Name, NULL as Parent
from IDTable i 
 join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev1
 union
select i.ID, l.lev2 as Name, (select j.ID from IDTable j where j.Name = l.lev1)
from IDTable i 
 join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev2
 union
select i.ID, l.lev3 as Name, (select j.ID from IDTable j where j.Name = l.lev2)
from IDTable i 
 join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev3
```

now for completely get my answer I have 1 more question

How I can have also position of each field in my query. For example parent of TUBE, LCD, PLASMA are TELEVISIONS now I need position field value that gives value of each position (0, 1, 2, 3…) according to alphabetic order.

```
category_id   | name                   | parent |position

 +-------------+----------------------+--------+-------
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |0
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |0
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |3
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |1
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use row_number() function with a partition.

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by parent order by name) as position from (
    select i.ID, l.lev1 as Name, NULL as Parent
    from IDTable i 
     join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev1
     union
    select i.ID, l.lev2 as Name, (select j.ID from IDTable j where j.Name = l.lev1)
    from IDTable i 
     join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev2
     union
    select i.ID, l.lev3 as Name, (select j.ID from IDTable j where j.Name = l.lev2)
    from IDTable i 
     join LevelTable l on i.Name = l.lev3
) as q
```